# Nginx redirecting with 2 different tomcats

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I'd like to share my issue with you. I have two different restApis which are deployed in separate Tomcat (port 8082 and 8084). The 2 deployment are well working and I can reach both of the apps with my browser.
Now I want to make a kind of gateway with Nginx in order to acces my apps with a url argument (for instance), so I configured the nginx.conf as it :

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

upstream genialoserv {
    server  127.0.0.1:8082;
}

upstream connexionserv {
    server  127.0.0.1:8084;
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:83;
    server_name genialo;

    location /gen {
        # Proxy all the requests to Tomcat
        proxy_pass  http://genialoserv/;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    }

    location /con {
        # Proxy all the requests to Tomcat
        proxy_pass  http://connexionserv/;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    }
}       
}
```

The result is when I go in my localhost:83 I reach the welcome page of Nginx as I want BUT when I want to reach localhost:83/gen or localhost:83/con I can't acces to the api's resources.

For information I work on windows 7 with tomcat8 and Nginx 1.10 and the apis are both .war.

Comment: Is the working application at `localhost:8082/gen/` or `localhost:8082/`? If its the latter, both applications will be looking for their resources at `localhost:83/` which is difficult to untangle.

Comment: it's at localhost:8082/gen, and that's the reason it didn't work well, the redirecting was wrong. I've changed it to localhost:8082/gen and it works. Thanks a lot I mark the topic as Resolved :)

Comment: Post the solution you found as a proper **answer**. You can even accept it, if you like.